# .NET 5 (Core) MVC - Model Binding DateTime using en-GB not working on GET but works fine on POST

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a new .NET 5 web application which is configured:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            opts =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> {new CultureInfo("en-GB"),};

                opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-GB", uiCulture: "en-GB");

            });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

I am then using:

```
        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        app.UseRouting();
```

My test form:

```
<form method="get" asp-action="TestGet" asp-controller="Home">
    <h2>test get</h2>
     <input type="text" id="From" name="From" value="15/12/2020">
    <button type="submit">go</button>
</form>

<form method="post" asp-action="TestPost" asp-controller="Home">
    <h2>test post</h2>
    <input type="text" id="From" name="From" value="15/12/2020">
    <button type="submit">go</button>
</form>
```

My actions:

```
[HttpGet]
        public RedirectResult TestGet(DateTime from)
        {
            var me = from;
            return Redirect("/");
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public RedirectResult TestPost(DateTime from)
        {
            var me = from;
            return Redirect("/");
        }
```

Expected result is that the date is bound in both instances, however this only works on post. On the get the date is not set.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the problem. Its by design to be invariant - thus allowing query strings to be shared.

Issue detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#globalization-behavior-of-model-binding-route-data-and-query-strings